# Referencing RealityKit Component

Tags: swift, realitykit

I’m implementing a RealityKit Entity Component System and have an issue with my component definition. Here is a simple example of what I’m doing:

```
import Foundation
import RealityFoundation

public struct ValueComponent: Component, Codable {
    public var value: Int = 0
}

public protocol HasValueComponent {}

extension HasValueComponent where Self: Entity {
    var value: Int {
        get { components[ValueComponent.self]?.value ?? 0 }
        set { components[ValueComponent.self]?.value = newValue }
    }
}
```

After creating a entity I initialize the component like this:

```
// ValueComponent.registerComponent()
modelEntity.name = "model"
modelEntity.components[ValueComponent.self] = .init(value: 123)
```

Later I try to access the component but always get nil. The component exists in the components set but the cast to HasValueComponent fails.

```
guard let model = arView.scene.findEntity(named: "model") as? Entity & HasValueComponent else { return }
print(model.components[ValueComponent.self])
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RealityKit (and RealityFoundation), you have to call a `registerComponent()` type method once for every ***custom*** component type that you want to use in your app, before you use it.

```
public static func registerComponent()
```

You don’t need to call this method for built-in component types, like `CollisionComponent`.

```
ValueComponent.registerComponent()
```

The same way you have to call `registerSystem()` type method to use a System (ECS pattern).

### Solution

Seems that type casting to protocols that implement custom components isn't supported. Inexplicably why. Thus, use the following solution.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

protocol HasValueComponent { }

extension HasValueComponent where Self: Entity {
    var val: Int {
        get { components[ValueComponent.self]?.val ?? .zero }
        set { components[ValueComponent.self]?.val = newValue }
    }
}   
struct ValueComponent: Component {
    var val: Int
}
```

`Primitive.swift`

```
class Primitive: Entity, HasModel, HasValueComponent {
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        
        ValueComponent.registerComponent()
        
        self.model = ModelComponent(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1),
                               materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
        self.name = "model"
        self.components.set(ValueComponent(val: 1234))            
    }
}
```

`ViewController.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let primitive = Primitive()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(arView)

        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(self.primitive)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        
        if let model = arView.scene.findEntity(named: "model") {
            print(model.components[ValueComponent.self]!.val)      // 1234
            print(model.components.has(ValueComponent.self))       // true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy Jazz. I did not know about registerComponent. After adding it I still see this:


(lldb) po arView.scene.findEntity(named: "model")?.components[ValueComponent.self]
▿ Optional<Component>
  ▿ some : ValueComponent
    - value : 123

(lldb) po arView.scene.findEntity(named: "model")?.components[ValueComponent.self] as? HasValueComponent
nil

Shouldn't I be able to cast to HasValueComponent?

Comment: Thanks Andy, looks like the cast is not possible, perhaps unless Entity is subclassed (I thought the whole point of components is to avoid subclassing). has() is key to this solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Andy, where do we need to execute MyComponent.registerComponent() and MySystem.registerSystem() ? It says the "app delegate" but I can't find it.

Comment: Hi @mesqueeb, in UIKit it's AppDelegate class, in SwiftUI – YourNameApp struct.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291654/swiftui-appdelegate-on-macos